# Change image on mouse over

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<img onmouseover="http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign2.png"
     align="right"
     alt="facebook"
     name="facebook"
     width="231"
     height="231"
     border="0"
     id="facebook"
     style="margin-top: -12px; margin-right: -60px;">
```

Its not working. It comes up as a box, not a broken image but a box which doesn't display the image. I'm adding it to my website, could i be putting it in the wrong place? Also, i put it in my forum wrapper and i want the image to be displayed and when you hover your mouse over it so it changes to image 2 please help.

Comment: What is `it` which is not working?

Comment: CODE PLEASE so that we can identify the IT :P

Comment: My Code didn't come up OMG! help me please dont leave

Comment: <img onmouseover="http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign2.png" align="right" alt="facebook" name="facebook" width="231" height="231" border="0" id="facebook" style="margin-top: -12px; margin-right: -60px;">
<img onmouseout="http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign2.png" align="right" alt="facebook" name="facebook" width="231" height="231" border="0" id="facebook" style="margin-top: -12px; margin-right: -60px;">

Comment: @Absorption I fixed your code for you

Comment: wow that was quick, really i hope it works but dont go i need to know where to place it

Comment: Maybe read some tutorial before doing anything else, you should understand what you're doing, not just copy and paste.

Comment: I dont understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend the image to change on mouseover, you can use this:

```html
<img onmouseover="this.src='http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign.png'"
     onmouseout="this.src='http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign2.png'"
     src="http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign2.png"
     align="right"
     alt="facebook"
     name="facebook"
     width="231"
     height="231"
     border="0"
     id="facebook"
     style="margin-top: -12px; margin-right: -60px;">
```

```
this.src='something'
```

will set the image src to `something`.

However, it would be prettier to use CSS and have it as background image, then it will work without javascript.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66816/discussion-on-answer-by-mightypork-change-image-on-mouse-over).

Answer (score 0):

Please use some CSS, that inline style code gets so confusing.

If you want to do it the nice way do something like this:

```css
#facebook {
    background: url("http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign2.png") no-repeat;
    width: 231px;
    height: 231px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-right: -60px;
}
#facebook:hover {
    background: url("http://www.habbohut.com/_images/_content/_habbohut/facebook_sign.png") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="facebook"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be right but from looking at your code your img script doesnt end.

You need to have `/>`

Comment: **HTML4** doesn't have self-closing elements, and the `/>` means something else entirely. In **HTML5**, the `/` character in [start tags](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#start-tags) has no effect on [void elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements) (such as `img`).

Comment: So i should add /> to it?

Comment: That is what I would try but again I am not sure if it will, if it does please tell me.